# WordPress Custom Application form

Tags: plugins, forms

- I want to implement an application form with WordPress, Preferably using a plugin. What I need here is not a contact us form, But I need a complete registration form or customer registration form or student registration form. This means fields could be customized according to particular need.

or

- I want a fixed number of columns table plugin which has a form and store data to that table. Because i want to show that table in my reports under wordpress admin panel.

I am open to any suggestion. Even if i am going totally wrong. Please guide me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Although a premium plugin, I would like to suggest [Gravity Forms](http://senl.in/gRaVitY) (aff link). Due to conditional logic you can easily adapt the form to be(come) an application form instead of the usual contact form.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [cforms](http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/). You can customize almost every aspect of the form to fit your particular needs. I have used it several times to make application forms and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Don't let it's name dissuade you, but I'd recommend [Contact Form 7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/). It has many ways to hook into it to do whatever you want with the form data. I've used it for application forms, for donation forms, etc. I've found it to be far simpler than cforms and thus much easier to work with.